# Pass Object to Lua Script from C#

Tags: c#, lua, luainterface

I am using LuaInterface with C#, and have got everything set up correctly.

What I want to be able to do is that when the script is started using lua.DoFile(), that the script has access to a Player object that I can send...

Current Code:

```
public static void RunQuest(string LuaScriptPath, QPlayer Player)
{
    QMain.lua.DoFile(LuaScriptPath);
}
```

But as you can see the script will not have access to the Player object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see two options. The first one is to make your player a global variable for Lua:

```
QMain.lua['player'] = Player
```

Then you'll be able to access `player` in your script

The second option is to have the script define a function accepting player as parameter. So if your current script contains `...code...` now it will contain:

```
function RunQuest(player)
    ...code...
end
```

and your C# code will look something like this:

```
public static void RunQuest(string LuaScriptPath, QPlayer Player)
{
    QMain.lua.DoFile(LuaScriptPath); // this will not actually run anything, just define a function
    QMain.lua.GetFunction('RunQuest').Call(player);        
}
```