# How do you pass an object from c# to lua's function?

Tags: c#, .net, lua, luainterface

I'm using Lua interface on c# to pass an object I created to lua's function.
It successfully calls the function, but lua is keep throwing an error:

**LuaInterface.LuaException: /hook.lua:32: attempt to index local 'objj' (a nil value)**

This is the c# code:

```c#
public class PerObj
{
    public string name;
    public PerObj() 
    {
    }
}

PerObj obj = new PerObj();
LuaFunction lf = lua.GetFunction ("item.HookMe");
lf.Call(obj);
```

And here's the lua code:

```lua
function item:HookMe(objj)
    objj.name= "lalala"
end
```

The function is actually being called, but I'm not sure it's not working...

Comment: This may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724791/pass-object-to-lua-script-from-c-sharp

Comment: I tried that before. Still thows "a nill value"

Comment: `item:HookMe(objj)` implies that you are passing two parameters to `HookMe` function. First one is `self` and the second is `objj`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the function definition to:

```
function item.HookMe(objj)
    objj.name= "lalala"
end
```

The colon in the original definition means that the function has also the `self` parameter. Those function are called like this: `object:HookMe()`. But you want to call it directly, so the colon is not applicable.

Edit:
If you want to keep the function defininition and retain `self`, call it like this:

```
lf.Call(null, obj);
```

To call it passing also the `self` object:

```
lf.Call(lua["item"], obj);
```

Comment: Thanks! If this has a self parameter, if I call the function (object:HookMe()) with :"lf.Call(null, obj);", what would happen? Would it be simply ignored? How would I retain "self" when I call the function?

Comment: @Max Yes, you can simply pass null as the first argument to `self`.

Comment: This makes "self" (also used in the function) nil. What are some other ways to retain self?

Comment: @Max It depends on what you expect `self` to be. If `item` is an object, you can call it like this: `Call(lua["item"], objj)`

Comment: Hm, then there's no way to let Lua interface ignore the first argument so "self" works when it's called through object:HookMe ()?

Comment: @Max I don't understand. In Lua, you implicitly specify the `self` argument in the "colon call". If you do `object:HookMe()`, it's exactly the same as `object.HookMe(object)`. You just have to specify the object you want to call the function on.

Comment: Oh yes, I got what you meant. Sorry if my question wasn't clear. If you were calling woop:HookMe(obj) through C#, I want to call the function using .Call(<?>, obj). if I put null for <?>, "self" in Lua would return "nil" instead of "woop". I want "self" to return itself in Lua while being able to use "Call ()" from C#.

Comment: @Max Lua function don't have "self" attached to them, if you write `func = woop:HookMe` and then `func(obj)`, the `obj` will be passed as `self` and the original `woop` will be lost. `self` is just a syntactic sugar for the first parameter, not something special.

Comment: I see. That's really weird. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem is the design of the Lua method (but it really depends on the intent):

Instead of

```
function item:HookMe(objj)
    -- self not used
    objj.name= "lalala"
end
```

This would work better in the given example:

```
function item:HookMe()
    self.name= "lalala"
end
```

The reason (as well discussed in other answers) is that declaring a function with the method syntax (`:`) adds an implied first formal parameter `self`. The caller *can* pass anything as the first actual argument but the contract is usually to pass the parent table of the function so it can access its sibling fields.

In this case, `name` seems to be a sibling of `HookMe` so the method shouldn't be operating on an arbitrary table passed as `objj` but instead on `self`.